# How to convert SQLResult into a Human readable output i.e. natural language output

Tags: python, sql, list, tuples

let say I have SQLResult as List of Tuples and the count of tuples in List is let say high, now I want to convert that into a Human readable output, How can I do so with Python.

Example :

Question : Give the stores list with total sales.

SQLResult : [('Adyar', 36283), ('Agra', 31892), ('Alibaug', 36623), ('Alwarpet', 34319), ('Andheri West', 34885), ('Anjuna', 36218), ('Ashok Nagar', 31804), ('Auli', 37329), ('Aundh', 34861), ('Bandra Kurla Complex', 33221), ('Banjara Hills', 33001), ('Bhagalpur', 34321), ('Bikaner', 34466), ('Camp', 32721), ('Chamba', 33681), ('Cherrapunji', 37580), ('Colaba', 36341), ('Coonoor', 36625),]

Desired Output : The stores list with total sales are as follows:

1. Adyar - 36283
2. Agra - 31892
3. Alibaug - 36623
4. Alwarpet - 34319
5. Andheri West - 34885
6. Anjuna - 36218
7. Ashok Nagar - 31804
8. Auli - 37329
9. Aundh - 34861
10. Bandra Kurla Complex - 33221
11. Banjara Hills - 33001
12. Bhagalpur - 34321
13. Bikaner - 34466
14. Camp - 32721
15. Chamba - 33681
16. Cherrapunji - 37580
17. Colaba - 36341
18. Coonoor - 36625

Now, I want solution that How can I do this dynamically with python.

I was trying with loops, but there was a problem with dynamic message.

Answer (score 0):

With [`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals):

```
res =  [('Adyar', 36283), ('Agra', 31892), ('Alibaug', 36623), ('Alwarpet', 34319), ('Andheri West', 34885), ('Anjuna', 36218), ('Ashok Nagar', 31804), ('Auli', 37329), ('Aundh', 34861), ('Bandra Kurla Complex', 33221), ('Banjara Hills', 33001), ('Bhagalpur', 34321), ('Bikaner', 34466), ('Camp', 32721), ('Chamba', 33681), ('Cherrapunji', 37580), ('Colaba', 36341), ('Coonoor', 36625),]

for idx, (name, val) in enumerate(res, 1):
    print(f'{idx}. {name} - {val}')
```

Output:

```
1. Adyar - 36283
2. Agra - 31892
3. Alibaug - 36623
4. Alwarpet - 34319
5. Andheri West - 34885
6. Anjuna - 36218
7. Ashok Nagar - 31804
8. Auli - 37329
9. Aundh - 34861
10. Bandra Kurla Complex - 33221
11. Banjara Hills - 33001
12. Bhagalpur - 34321
13. Bikaner - 34466
14. Camp - 32721
15. Chamba - 33681
16. Cherrapunji - 37580
17. Colaba - 36341
18. Coonoor - 36625
```

If you need a [pager](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/console.html#paging), use [`rich`](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library:

```
# pip install rich
from rich.console import Console

res = [('Adyar', 36283), ('Agra', 31892), ('Alibaug', 36623), ('Alwarpet', 34319), ('Andheri West', 34885), ('Anjuna', 36218), ('Ashok Nagar', 31804), ('Auli', 37329), ('Aundh', 34861), ('Bandra Kurla Complex', 33221), ('Banjara Hills', 33001), ('Bhagalpur', 34321), ('Bikaner', 34466), ('Camp', 32721), ('Chamba', 33681), ('Cherrapunji', 37580), ('Colaba', 36341), ('Coonoor', 36625),]

out = '\n'.join(f'{idx}. {name} - {val}' for idx, (name, val) in enumerate(res, 1))

console = Console()
with console.pager():
    console.print(out)
```